# How do I compare two arrays filled with hashes and return the hashes that are not present in the second?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, compare

Let's say I have two arrays filled with hashes,

```
array_a = [{'key' => 'a'}, {'key' => 'b'}, {'key' => 'c'}, {'key' => 'd'}]
array_b = [{'key' => 'a'}, {'key' => 'b'}, {'key' => 'd'}]
```

how do I compare `array_a` and `array_b` and return the hash that was not found in `array_b`.

So the compare should return:

```
# => [{'key' => 'c'}]
```

Comment: Note that your question has nothing to do with hashes; it's just about elements of two arrays, whatever objects they may be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Array#-`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-2D) would work:

```
array_a = [{'key' => 'a'}, {'key' => 'b'}, {'key' => 'c'}, {'key' => 'd'}]
array_b = [{'key' => 'a'}, {'key' => 'b'}, {'key' => 'd'}]

array_a - array_b
#=> [{"key"=>"c"}]
```

The method *"… compares elements using their `hash` and `eql?` methods …"* and according to [`Hash#hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-hash):

> Two hashes with the same content will have the same hash code (and will compare using `eql?`).